# ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup on client side to prevent xss

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xss

In our react.js based codebase, we use an external library which accepts raw html, and we had xss issues due to code like:

```
'<div title="' + dangerousTitle + ' ">' + dangerousText + '</div>';
```

I need to come up with a policy for the team and it seemed possible to use:

```
ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(
     <div title={dangerousTitle}>
         {dangerousText}
     </div>
);
```

On the client side code. However, in react documentation, it is explicitly stated that renderToStaticMarkup is for server side use.

Assuming we know what we are doing, does anybody have any argument against above use?

PS: we considered _.escape, _.template with <%-, `` template strings with escaping function, above seemed the best fit since the team is already used to react templates more than anything else.

Comment: I would suggest checking how much including `ReactDOMServer` in the client side increases the size of the codebase. Otherwise I think it should be ok.

Comment: It is a very small addition. But it might get refactored to something really big in the future with e.g. file io thus it might not be possible to use it in the future. I want to hear some insider knowledge if any to be future proof.

Comment: We are considering doing the same thing in our codebase. We learned a long time ago that there is no future proofing in the React world.